# While loop with some if statements getting super high numbers

Tags: c

I'm doing a border game in C and I'm having some issues with my while loop and the values that I'm getting in the output.

I have an array with some random values in it, from -5 ti 5 in 20% of the board. and what I'm trying to do is just add that value to my variable called player.

```
int player1 = 0, player2 = 0, player3 = 0, player4 = 0;
int dice = 0, number_of_players = 0, number_of_players = 2;


while(player1 < 50 && player2 < 50){
    if(number_of_players == 2){
        dice = (rand() % 6) + 1;
        player1 += dice;
        if(border[player1] != 0){
            player1 = player1 + (border[player1]);
        }      
        dice = (rand() % 6) + 1;
        player2 += dice;      
        if(border[player2] != 0){
            player2 = player2 + (border[player2]);
        }      
    }   
}
if(player1 > player2) printf("Player 1 won. Score: %d", player1);
if(player2 > player1) printf("Player 2 won. Score: %d", player2);
```

This is the code for my array called "border", it's above my while loop:

```
#define TAM 50

int border[TAM], i, pos, casas;
for( i=0; i<TAM; i++ )
    border[i] = 0;

i = 0;
while( i < (int)TAM*0.1 ){
    pos = rand() % TAM;
    if( border[pos] == 0 ){
        casas = (rand() % 5) + 1;
        border[pos] = casas;
        i++;
    }
}

i = 0;

while( i < (int)TAM*0.1 ){
    pos = rand() % TAM;
    if(border[pos] == 0){
        casas = (rand() % 5) + 1; 
        border[pos] = casas * (-1);
        i++;
    }
}
```

the ouput sometimes is 50, that I have no idea how it is getting because it only stops the loop when a player reaches 51 or upper. I'm also getting super high values like: 299158477.
I'm newbie in C. thanks everyone.

Comment: *The ouput sometimes is 50*. The output of what? I don't see any output statements. *I'm also getting super high values like: 299158477.* Super high values for what?

Comment: @lurker as the output for the players

Comment: Smells like uninitialised variables. Or exceeding array bounds with the suspicious `player1 = player1 + (border[player1]);`

Comment: When/where do you check the *output for the players*? And if `number_of_players` isn't 2, you have potentially an infinite loop depending upon values for `player1` and `player2`. Which, by the way, where are those initialized, and what are they set to (alluding to @WeatherVane comment). And what does your `border` array look like?

Comment: @WeatherVane I have this code in the beginning:
    int player1 = 0, player2 = 0, player3 = 0, player4 = 0;
    int dice = 0, number_of_players = 0;

Comment: @lurker I'm checking the value of the players in the while loop. It should stop when a player reaches more than 50. I'm just testing with number_of_players as 2 so far. My array looks like this: 0   0   0   0   0   -4  0   -2  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   -1   5   0   0   0   2   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -1  0   0   0   0   -2

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. You're referencing problems that can't be answered with the code you've posted. You don't show where any of the variables are declared and initialized, where this code is called from, and where and how you're evaluating the output. We can't debug code we cannot see.

Comment: @KenWhite I've just updated the question. Does it look better now?

Comment: I'm afraid not. A [mcve] should be a block of code that can be copied, pasted into a code editor, saved and compiled (and executed, if the issue is at runtime) in order to reproduce the issue. You've not yet provided that [mcve].

Comment: It would look a lot better if a reader could easily cut-n-paste from your question and compile/run your code.  But that's not necessary here.  It is pretty clear that you are accessing the array out of bounds.

Comment: Hint: suppose player2 = 48 and is incremented by a random value between 1 and 6.  If player2 > 50 and you attempt to reference `border[player2]`, what happens?

Comment: @WilliamPursell THANKS, I've just realized it. I changed my code and now it's working properly. ;). I was trying to access an array element that's not defined. so, I just put that if player1 > 50 break for both players and so far so good. Thanks for everyone.

Comment: What can happen when `border[1] == -3`?

Comment: @Bob__ whoops that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

> int dice = 0, **number_of_players** = 0, **number_of_players** = 2;

Your code should not be compilable, with a variable declared twice.

---

```
if(border[player1] != 0){
    player1 = player1 + (border[player1]);
```

You do not need the `if()`. If `border` is zero, then the result will not change.

---

```
i = 0;
while( i < (int)TAM*0.1 ){
    pos = rand() % TAM;
    if( border[pos] == 0 ){
        casas = (rand() % 5) + 1;
        border[pos] = casas;
        i++;
    }
}
```

This `while()` should be a `for()`.

---

```
while( i < (int)TAM*0.1 ){
```

should be

```
while( i < (TAM/10) ){
```

---

```
casas = (rand() % 5) + 1;
```

maybe should be:

```
casas = (rand() % 6) + 1;
```

because you have dice? Not so relevant, anyway, for the logic of the code.

---

When `player1` becomes >= TAM (after `player1 += dice;`), you access memory outside of `border`

```
player1 = player1 + (border[player1]);
```